# Access Azure Service Fabric application from internet

Tags: azure, tcp, azure-service-fabric

I think I'm missing something that is on surface.
I have created SF cluster in Azure. It has a Load Balancer and a network with 3 VMs (nodes) which have IP addresses in 10.0.0.0/16.

When I'm asking Load balancer for application endpoint it responds with node IP address. (I captured packets with WireShark) But I can't access it because the network is private.

A bit more info about my case: 3xA0 instances, net.tcp:20001 endpoints, firewall allow connections, ports opened and listening, i have public IP address assigned to balancer, probe for service port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok Here is it:

**When you want to communicate to the service from outside the cluster** - just use load balancer IP and you don't need the naming server communication. Load balancer has probs that can check ports on each node in cluster and forward your request to random instance which has service you are asking.

**When you want to communicate one microservice to another within the cluster** then you have 2 options:

1. ask naming service through load balancer and then communicate to the service directly.
2. if you know for sure that the service should be on every node in your cluster - you can just communicate to localhost directly.

**When you want to communicate from separate vm to the microservice in the cluster from within cluster's virtual network** (you can connect WebApp to the cluster using vpn) then you can ask naming service through load balancer but using Service fabric HTTP API because you will not be able to use service fabric classes on VM wich doesn't have Service Fabric SDK installed. Here is an example of service resolving: https://github.com/lAnubisl/ServiceFabricHttpApiClient

Answer (score 1):

On your load balancer you will need to assign a public IP address. You can find some really good detailed guides in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-get-started-internet-arm-ps) for this.

Comment: My Load balancer has public ip address. I can access it and it and it responds me with node's endpoints. I have probes and other stuff from the documentation. The problem is that none of my vm's have public ip addresses and load balancer just replies me where should i connect (it wants me to connect directly to nodes). I was expecting it will pass traffic through.

Comment: That's right you don't want your VMs having public IPs. Have you tried configuring direct return on the load balancing rules? We need to do this for SQL AAGs.

Comment: Yes. My balancing rule has Frontend ip address = load balancer public ip, Protocol = TCP, port = my service port, backend pool = my vm scalability group, probe, session persistence = Client IP, Floating IP = true.Same effect. My client application says "Can't connect to 10.0.0.5:20001/....."

Comment: Does your VM that sits on 10.0.0.5 have a Network Security Group associated with it?